# How to get non-aggregated measures?

Tags: postgresql, tableau-api

I calculate my metrics with SQL and publish the resulting table to Tableau Server. Afterward, use this data source to create charts and dashboards.

For one analysis, I already calculated the measures per day with SQL. When I use the resulting table in Tableau, it aggregates these measures to SUM by default. However, I don't want to have SUM or AVG of the average or SUM of the Percentiles.
[image]

What I want is the result when I don't select date dimension and not GROUP BY date in SQL as attached below.
[image]

Here is the query:

```
    SELECT
--  date,
    COUNT(DISTINCT id) AS count_of_id,
    AVG(timediff_in_sec) AS avg_timediff,
    PERCENTILE_CONT(0.25) WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY timediff_in_sec) AS percentile_25,
    PERCENTILE_CONT(0.50) WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY timediff_in_sec) AS percentile_50
FROM
(
--subquery
) AS t1

-- GROUP BY date
```

Here are the first 10 rows of the resulting table:

```
+------------+--------------+-------------+---------------+---------------+
|    date    | avg_timediff | count_of_id | percentile_25 | percentile_50 |
+------------+--------------+-------------+---------------+---------------+
| 10/06/2020 |  61,65186364 |          22 |        8,5765 |       13,3015 |
| 11/06/2020 |  127,2913333 |           3 |       15,6045 |        17,494 |
| 12/06/2020 |  306,0348214 |          28 |       12,2565 |        17,629 |
| 13/06/2020 |      13,2664 |           5 |        11,944 |        13,862 |
| 14/06/2020 |       16,728 |           7 |        14,021 |        17,187 |
| 15/06/2020 |  398,6424595 |          37 |        11,893 |        19,271 |
| 16/06/2020 |  293,6925152 |          33 |        12,527 |        17,134 |
| 17/06/2020 |  155,6554286 |          21 |        13,452 |        16,715 |
| 18/06/2020 |  383,8101429 |           7 |       266,048 |       493,722 |
+------------+--------------+-------------+---------------+---------------+
```

How can I achieve the desired output above?

Comment: (1) Tag with the database you are using (where the SQL is running).  (2) Put the query in your question as *text* not an image.

Comment: Please add the original data. You have written what you get, you have written what you want, but we do not know from what data do you wish to get that ?? Also, as Gordon wrote above, add text instead of images . So, text and data. Without that ... we can not help alot...

Comment: The resulting table is 99 rows, I just added the first 10 rows. Here I posted the Tableau workbook if needed https://community.tableau.com/s/question/0D54T00000JHlAmSAL/how-to-get-nonaggregated-measures

Answer (score 1):

Drag them all into the dimensions list, then they will be static dimensions. For your use you could also just drag the Date field to Rows. Aggregating 1 value, which you have for each date, returns the same value whatever the aggregation type.